# What is the use of draft tag in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Looking at the questions, I saw this tag: [draft](/questions/tagged/draft).

I found it very confusing and useless. 
What is the use of it and what can I do start a deletion process for it using meta.

Comment: Only 16 questions, it could be manually removed from all questions and then auto-deleted